# Is it possible to see the SQL query of a LINQ command?

Tags: .net, sql, linq

It would help me understand LINQ a little bit better that's all.

I tried using the SQL Profiler but I'm not sure how I can get it to show the actual SQL commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ScottGu's blog has a great post on the subject here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/01/Understanding-LINQ-to-SQL-Query-Translations.aspx

There is a query visualizer you can use by hovering over the object in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Log property of the DataContext object:

```
using (var dc = new DataContext())
{
    dc.Log = Console.Out;  // Outputs the SQL statement to a System.IO.TextWriter object

    var customers = dc.Customers.Single(c => c.Customer_ID == 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using **LINQ-SQL** then the best way is to use *SQL Profiler*. Your probably missing something in your trace profiler. Turn everything on, see the trace, then modify the trace profile accordingly.

If your using **LINQ-Entities** then there is an `ObjectQuery<T>` extension method called `.ToTraceString()` which will give you the SQL that is to be executed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the Profiler's Trace Properties window, Events Selection tab: select "Show all events", then under the TSQL section, ensure SQL:StmtStarting or SQL:BatchStarting is checked, then make sure the TextData column is checked.

When you run your trace, the TextData column will contain the SQL.

Have to second ScottGu's blog post for this, and his blog in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) ... you can create a standard Linq query and it will show you what it would look like leveraging expressions and standard Transact-Sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a watch to your variable in debug mode and the value of your object will be the SQL query.